# Gatling loadtest gets different rpc than expected

Tags: kotlin, load-testing, gatling

I am trying to make a loadtest using Gatling but I can't get it to work as I want.

I have 3 scenarios that should run sequentially According to [Gatling docs](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/injection/#sequential-scenarios) I should use `andThen` to achive that, so this is my code:

```
init {
        setUp(
            scenario1.injectOpen(
                rampUsersPerSec(startRate).to(maxRate).during(rampupSeconds),
                constantUsersPerSec(maxRate).during(plateauSeconds),
            ).andThen(
                scenario2.injectOpen(
                    rampUsersPerSec(startRate).to(maxRate).during(rampupSeconds),
                    constantUsersPerSec(maxRate).during(plateauSeconds),
                )
            ).andThen(
                scenario3.injectOpen(
                    rampUsersPerSec(startRate).to(maxRate).during(rampupSeconds),
                    constantUsersPerSec(maxRate).during(plateauSeconds),
                ),
            )
        )
            .maxDuration(3 * (rampupSeconds + plateauSeconds))
            .assertions(
                 ...
            )
    }
```

Each scenario consists of one single request and `maxRate = 2000` however when I run the loadtest I see that `rps` gets much higher than `2000` and I can't figure out why.

The strange part is sometimes it just works fine, others `rps` becomes about `4.5K`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

maxRate is a virtual user arrival rate, not a number of requests per second. They are equal only when your scenario consists of one single request.

Comment: Each scenario consists of one single request, I will add that to the description.

Comment: Can’t say without you providing a reproducer then. Also make sure to use the latest version.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share more code :( Thanks for your help anyway :D

Comment: You can build a sample based on a public website and exhibits the same behavior. Or become a customer so you can get private support and NDA.